# Calculate the average payment between dates for only positive amounts

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame containing date and payment columns. Both columns also contain some NA values. The question is to calculate the average payments with a date between January 1, 2009 and December 31, 2015 ,consider only positive payments, and remove NA values from the calculation.

Here is my code:

```
average <- mean(df$payment[which(df$payment > 0)] [with(df, df$date >= "2009-01-01" & df$date <= "2015-12-31", na.rm = TRUE)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

No error from the above code. Is it correct? Or any suggestion for a better idea?

Truly appreciate any help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'date' column to `Date` class (in case it is not converted), then subset the 'payment' by creating a logical vector with payment greater than 0 and (`&`) the 'date' column values are in the range from '2009-01-01' to '2015-12-31', get the `mean`

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
with(df,  mean(payment[payment > 0 & 
                       date >= as.Date("2009-01-01") & 
                       date <= as.Date("2015-12-31")], na.rm = TRUE))
```